# conversion of sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr

Tags: sensor-msgs, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
How can I convert sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr
to sensor_msgs::PointCloud2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65046/conversion-of-sensor_msgs::pointcloud2constptr/) by [xelda1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/4742/xelda1988/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Say you have input as sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr and output as sensor_msgs::PointCloud2. output = *input;

---

Originally posted by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) with karma: 166 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-14**:
Just a small addition to this answer. That's because the first (PointCloud2ConstPtr) is a pointer (Ptr), hence the *

**Comment by [xelda1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/4742/xelda1988/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thanks guys! Is this copying the pointcloud, which allocates new memory? If yes, is there another way to do it?

**Comment by [ashish](https://answers.ros.org/users/23237/ashish/) on 2017-06-01**:
This might be a really 'new' comment.
ConstPtr types are typedef(s) for boost::shared_ptr (shared pointer) to manage the life-cycle of pointer-memories. There won't be any new memory allocated but reuse of an already allocated memory.